# Why is this simple rewriterule failing to function?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have two rules to redirect to relevant front controllers:

```
RewriteRule ^api/?.*$ api.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ web.php [NC,L]
```

Is there a reason why `localhost/api/a` fails to be caught by the first rule?

Comment: Trying to narrow down whether the problem is here or another configuration.

Comment: What's your RewriteBase?

Comment: I don't have one, but get the same result with /. The .htaccess file's definitely being loaded because placing a syntax error in there triggers a 501.

Comment: If its an .htaccess file you might need a RewriteBase.

Comment: I tested this and it worked for me.

Comment: Do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: My bad, I had a REWRITE_COND set incorrectly (should have included it but assumed it was correct) - thanks for helping anyway though.

More specifically, if you are checking REWRITE_FILENAME check it shouldn't be REWRITE_URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

If its in the root,

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/?.*$ api.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ web.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant I'd tried that but it made no difference. Yes it's in the root.